# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'guild')

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Help pls!

I have a error here:

```
let u_exp = bot.Memory.guilds[message.guild.id].members[member.id];
```

This a herself error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'guild')
```

how i can fix it?

Client.js:

```
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject, message) => {
        if (member == undefined) reject(`**member** not specified`);
        const user_id = member.id;
        
        // user db profile
        const u = getProfile(user_id);
        let bg = `./background.png`, 
            av = './avatar.png';
        if (![undefined, ``].includes(u.background)) bg = u.background;
        if (member.user.avatarURL({ format: "jpg" }) != null && member.user.avatarURL({ format: "jpg" }) != undefined) {
            av = member.user.avatarURL({ format: "jpg" });
        }

        let imageBg, imageOverlay, imageAvatar;
        try {
            // Check last update date
            if (fs.existsSync(`./profiles/${user_id}.png`)) {
                fs.stat(`./profiles/${user_id}.png`, function(err, stats) {
                    var date = new Date(stats["mtime"]);
                    if (timeDifference(date, Date.now()) < 10) {
                        resolve(true);
                    }
                });                
            }
            // load overlays
            imageBg = await loadImage(bg);
            imageOverlay = await loadImage('./overlay.png');
            imageAvatar = await loadImage(av);
        } catch (err) {
            reject(err)
        }

        // Main Canvas
        const canvas = createCanvas(400, 200);
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 200);

        // Bacground & Overlay
        context.drawImage(imageBg, 0, 0, 400, 200);
        context.drawImage(imageOverlay, 0, 0, 400, 200);
        
        // Avatar Canvas
        const canvasAvatar = createCanvas(98, 98);
        const contextAvatar = canvasAvatar.getContext('2d');
        contextAvatar.beginPath();
        contextAvatar.arc(98/2, 98/2, 98 / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); // circle center [x, y], radius
        contextAvatar.closePath();
        contextAvatar.clip();
        contextAvatar.drawImage(imageAvatar, 0, 0, 98, 98);
        contextAvatar.strokeStyle = "#000";
        contextAvatar.stroke();
        context.drawImage(canvasAvatar, 22, 67, 98, 98);

        // Shapes
        const canvasTriangle = createCanvas(98, 98);
        const contextTriangle = canvasTriangle.getContext('2d');
        contextTriangle.fillStyle = '#fff';
        contextTriangle.beginPath();
        contextTriangle.moveTo(98, 98 / 2);
        contextTriangle.lineTo(0, 0);
        contextTriangle.lineTo(0, 98);
        contextTriangle.closePath();
        contextTriangle.fill();
        context.drawImage(canvasTriangle, 22, 20, 20, 20);

        // User name
        registerFont('./10568.ttf', { family: 'Astakhov' });
        context.font = '24pt Astakhov';
        const title = member.nickname ? member.nickname: member.user.username;
        context.font = '24pt Astakhov';
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.fillText(title, 50, 48);
        context.fillStyle = '#fff';
        context.fillText(title, 48, 46);

        // Other text fields
        const lvl = `${u.lvl} LVL`;
        context.font = '10pt Astakhov';
        context.textAlign = 'center';
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.fillText(lvl, 73, 185);
        context.fillStyle = '#fff';
        context.fillText(lvl, 71, 183);

        // Exp text
        let u_exp = bot.Memory.guilds[message.guild.id].members[member.id];
        u_exp = Math.random() * 1000; // TODO Remove debug
        const exp = `${(u_exp/100).toFixed(1).replace(".0", "")}k/10k EXP`;
        context.textAlign = 'right';
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.fillText(exp, 375, 185);
        context.fillStyle = '#fff';
        context.fillText(exp, 373, 183);
        // Exp line
        const gradientWR = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 389, 0);
        gradientWR.addColorStop(0, "white");
        gradientWR.addColorStop(1, "red");
        context.fillStyle = gradientWR;
        context.fillRect(5, 188, Math.round((u_exp*389)/1000), 5);
        // context.fillText(exp, 373, 183);

        // Other text calculating
        const randomText = generateRandomString();
        let fontsize = 20;
        do {
            fontsize--;
            context.font = `${fontsize}px Astakhov`;
        } while (context.measureText(randomText).width > 215)
        context.textAlign = 'center';
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.fillText(randomText, 268, 90);
        context.fillStyle = '#fff';
        context.fillText(randomText, 266, 88);

        // Dynamic drawing [https://flaviocopes.com/canvas/]
        const canvasRainbow = createCanvas(400, 200);
        const contextRainbow = canvasRainbow.getContext('2d');
        for (let i = 0; i < canvasRainbow.height/5+1; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < canvasRainbow.width/5+1; j++) {
                contextRainbow.fillStyle = `rgb(${i * 5}, ${j * 5}, ${(i+j) * 50})`
                contextRainbow.fillRect(j * 5, i * 5, 5, 5)
            }
        }          
        // context.drawImage(canvasRainbow, 0, 0, 400, 200);
        
        // Export
        const buffer = canvas.toBuffer('image/png');
        fs.writeFileSync(`./profiles/${user_id}.png`, buffer);
        resolve();
    });
}
```

I need to make a users cards with js library canvas.

Comment: Where is `message` coming from? It's undefined

Comment: A Promise only takes two arguments, so you can't pass message in like that btw.

Answer (score -1):

The "message" has nothing in it, it cant read the guild from nothing. So you would haev to change the 3 objects into an array like this:

```js
return new Promise(async (InfoArray) => {
        resolve = InfoArray[0]
        reject = InfoArray[1]
        message = InfoArray[2]

}
```

But in order for that to work you will have t change the way you execute the proimise which most likely looking something like this `Promise.execute(resolve, reject, message)` into `Promise.execute([resolve, reject, message])`

Comment: at least i can comment on this

Comment: also id use an array with the 3 objects in it not them separately

Comment: How i can add a message?

Comment: I edited my response to hopefully help u